# Core 2 Duo Processor E8400 with LGA 755 socket?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core2, dell-xps, lga775

The motherboard on my PC (Dell XPS 410) has socket LGA 755 and according to the box on this processor I have, says it requires a motherboard with socket LGA 775.

Will this processor work on the 755 motherboard?

---

Edit: After reading further result online, I think I may have been fed some mis-information. According to [this thread](http://forums.cnet.com/5208-7586_102-0.html?threadID=204012) the XPS comes with socket LGA 755 but on other sites it says that it comes with LGA 775...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I question that its actualy a **socket 755**... most likely it IS LGA 775

As far as I am aware there is no such Intel socket: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775

Also checking AnandTech shows me this [article](http://www.anandtech.com/printarticle.aspx?i=2834). Which states that your XPS 410 is a LGA 775 socket mobo.

Check the article that I linked, it should give you an idea of what is supported or not.

Answer (score 1):

in a word, no

the XPS 410 features the 965g chipset and does not support the e8400, which requires 1333 MHz bus speed. the 965g chipset only supports 1066 MHz.

The XPS 410 has a Socket **LGA 775** motherboard.

i'd say the **[Intel® Core™2 Quad Processor Q6700](http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SLACQ)** is the fastest processor this board can support.

Comment: Ahhh, would this chip still be usable in the 410? Is it hazardous to run it on a lower bus speed chipset?

Comment: according to this thread, the poster upgraded his xps 410 with a q6600: http://en.community.dell.com/forums/t/19284677.aspx